# Maybe it is better to write all module filenames in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/__init__.py

Tags: python-3.x, module, initialization, urllib

By default ,you can't import modules in urllib in python3.9.

```
python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jul 14 2021, 09:15:03) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> dir(urllib)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

Let's check which module is in urllib.

```
ls  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/
error.py     parse.py     request.py   robotparser.py
__init__.py  __pycache__  response.py
cat /usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/__init__.py
#it contains blank line.

>>> import urllib
>>> web = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.yahoo.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'
```

The best practice is `import urllib.request` suggested on many tutorials online.
The `__init__.py` is blank ,contains nothing ,by default.So one have to write `import urllib.request` to import it,now i add the below lines in the `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/__init__.py`.

```
from . import error
from . import parse
from . import request
from . import robotparser
from . import response
```

Then to open a webpage:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> web = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.yahoo.com')
>>> web.info
<bound method HTTPResponse.info of <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f2654757430>>
```

Why the author doesn't add the lines in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/__init__.py`?

Comment: This can only be answered by the author(s) of urllib, so it isn't a useful question in my opinion.  Arguably there isn't much benefit in importing all the submodules into the package namespace, since `from urllib import request` will get you the submodule directly.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Git history in the Python 3 source code, for [`cpython/Lib/urllib/__init__.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/urllib/__init__.py), I found a single commit:

> Make a new urllib package. It consists of code from urllib, urllib2, urlparse, and robotparser. The old modules have all been removed.  The new package has five submodules: urllib.parse, urllib.request, urllib.response,
> urllib.error, and urllib.robotparser.  The urllib.request.urlopen() function uses the url opener from urllib2.

Then taking a look at the [Python 2 source history](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/2.7/Lib), it appears that those four libraries all originally existed as flat files.

So my *best guess* is that, in combining a handful of related libraries together during the transition from Python 2 to 3, they decided that this submodule structure would be the easiest to understand and maintain. Forcing the issue by way of the `__init__.py` file was likely meant to alleviate some confusion for end users with regards to the lineage of the methods: that is, which functions came originally from which Python 2 libraries. In essence, trading the marginal convenience of a top-level import for better modularity and clearer separation of concerns from the perspective of the users.